# How to make fire effect faster

Tags: smoke-simulation, effects

I am using a fire effect but its coming out too slowly I want it to kind of burst out instead of slowly flow out.
I just want the fire to reach its maximum height of its domain faster

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Maybe post some screenshots of what you have, or reference images of what you wish to achieve?

Comment: i don't know what to screenshot i literally just want the fire to get to the top of it domain faster

Comment: I have added a bit more detail

Answer (score 1):

The temperature difference setting, which is in both [domain](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html#settings) and [flow](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/flow_object.html#initial-values) objects, affects the speed at which the smoke moves.

[image: temperature setting]

Answer (score 0):

Give it a greater initial velocity.
Most likely on the Z-axis, if you want it to go up.

[image: Z-velo]

Comment: That is from particles, but smoke flow does have an initial velocity option as well.